# How to draw each object after an interval of time (JavaScript mini-game)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval

I'm working on a project for Uni and want to make a mini-game in JavaScript representing Guitar Heroes (https://www.gameinformer.com/s3/files/styles/body_default/s3/legacy-images/imagefeed/Reunion%20Tour%3A%20The%20Best%20And%20Worst%20Of%20Guitar%20Hero/Gh3_2D00_337_2D00_610.jpg) 
I only started learning JavaScript one month ago, but was attracted by the canvas library and decided to do my project with it.

I managed to make an array of circle Objects, each with a different speed and y-position and make them appear all together on the screen.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var g = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    //object
    function Circle(x, y, speed, radius){           this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.speed=speed;
        this.radius=radius;



        //methods for the object


        this.draw = function(){

                g.beginPath();
                g.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                g.fill();
                g.closePath();

            }

        this.update = function(){

                this.x += this.speed;
                this.draw();
            } 
    }

    var circleArray = [];

    for ( var i=0; i<10; i++){


        var stringA = 100;
        var stringS = 200;
        var stringD = 300;
        var stringF = 400;
        var array = [stringA, stringD, stringF, stringS];



        radius=40;

        var x= innerWidth - radius;
        var y=array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

        var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 4) ) + 4;  //(max-min) + min
        speed = -speed;


        circleArray.push(new Circle(x, y, speed, radius));
    }




    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);  
        g.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);



        //this is where it all went downhill - without setInterval method, it works



        setInterval( function(){
        for ( var i=0; i< circleArray.length; i++ ){
            circleArray[i].update();
        }
        }, 1000);
        //


        //lines
        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0, 100);
        g.lineTo(innerWidth, 100);
        g.strokeStyle = 'red';
        g.stroke();
        g.closePath();

        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0, 200);
        g.lineTo(innerWidth, 200);
        g.strokeStyle = 'red';
        g.stroke();
        g.closePath();

        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0, 300);
        g.lineTo(innerWidth, 300);
        g.strokeStyle = 'red';
        g.stroke();
        g.closePath();

        g.beginPath();
        g.moveTo(0, 400);
        g.lineTo(innerWidth, 400);
        g.strokeStyle = 'red';
        g.stroke();
        g.closePath();
        //


    }

    animate();
```

What I want to do next is to **make the circle objects appear on the screen one after each other.** Preferably after a random interval. But I can't get my head around the setInterval method. My idea was to make another setInterval method inside but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone show me how or point me to a tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: Keep the for-loop that updates the circles inside of the animate function, but take off `setInterval`.

 use `setInterval` around `animate()` call on the last line.

Comment: You're basically programming this bottom-up, but you need to use a top-down approach instead. Meaning you need to create the data structure representing the song first (using arrays), then move through them using a single interval and draw the screen based on the timing. In other words, you need to write code that can also be used to move divs around, or display the game state using a bunch of ASCII characters and a fixed width font. The underlying mechanism is always the same, and *it* is the crucial part.

Comment: Here's example code illustrating my point: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bhyL5o9q/

Comment: hei @ChrisG! thanks for the code, although the difficulty is a bit too high for me(meaning the syntax is a bit different and i only recently discovered there are other ways to display without using canvas), it inspires me to want to learn more javascript. My initial idea was to use objects, and if that won't be possible, i'll put your code into good work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this I'm declaring a new variable: `frames` and frames is increasing it's value with every `animate()` frame.

I'm creating the circles inside `animate()` and only if

```
if(frames % 27 == 0 && //you can choose a different number
   Math.random() < .5 && // for randomness
   circleArray.length <= 10){//limiting the total number of circles at 10
   circleArray.push(new Circle());}
```

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var g = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var frames = 0;

//object
function Circle() {
  this.array = [100, 300, 400, 200];
  this.radius = 40;
  this.x = innerWidth + this.radius;
  this.y = this.array[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  this.speed = -Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 4)) + 4;
  

  //methods for the object

  this.draw = function() {
    g.beginPath();
    g.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    g.closePath();
    g.fill();
    
  };

  this.update = function() {
    this.x += this.speed;
    // if the circle goes out of the canvas put it back 
    if(this.x < -this.radius){this.x = innerWidth + this.radius;}
    this.draw();
  };
}

var circleArray = [];


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  g.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  
  
  if(frames % 27 == 0 && 
     Math.random() < .5 && 
     circleArray.length <= 10){circleArray.push(new Circle());}
    for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
      circleArray[i].update();
    }
  
  
  
  drawLines();
  frames++

 
  
}

animate();




function drawLines(){
   //lines
  g.beginPath();
  g.moveTo(0, 100);
  g.lineTo(innerWidth, 100);
  g.strokeStyle = "red";
  g.stroke();
  g.closePath();

  g.beginPath();
  g.moveTo(0, 200);
  g.lineTo(innerWidth, 200);
  g.strokeStyle = "red";
  g.stroke();
  g.closePath();

  g.beginPath();
  g.moveTo(0, 300);
  g.lineTo(innerWidth, 300);
  g.strokeStyle = "red";
  g.stroke();
  g.closePath();

  g.beginPath();
  g.moveTo(0, 400);
  g.lineTo(innerWidth, 400);
  g.strokeStyle = "red";
  g.stroke();
  g.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey! this is exactly what I was trying to do:) Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

setInterval may not be what you want to use if you want a random amount of time between draws. Try doing something like this:

```
let randomDelay
for(int i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++){
    randomDelay = Math.random() * 100 //maximum number of milliseconds to wait
    setTimeout(() => {
         circleArray[i].update()
    }, randomDelay)
}
```

The reason your code doesn't do what you'd expect is because your for loop is inside of the interval, meaning all of them are getting updated "simultaneously" every 1 second

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly was I was doing now, but for some reason it gives me an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Comment: with my snippet or your current code? Maybe it's because when the timeout function  executes it can't read the circle array like that. Try saving circleArray[i] to a var and use the var

Comment: you were right, no more errors, but now the circles don't show up on the screen. there are still in the array tho.